# Issue in generating Query

Tags: sql

I am having two tables `cdr` and `cdr_01`

```
////Cdr////
id calling_no called_no call_date duration
1 9899767876 0112356788 01-jan-2012 160
2 9999758743 0244356788 01-jan-2012 191

////cdr_01/////
id calling_no called_no call_date duration
1 9999758743 0244356788 01-jan-2012 190
2 9899767876 0112356788 01-jan-2012 163
```

I want output corresponding to the two tables by matching each column instead of id
and if difference of duration is -1, 0 , 1 than that is to be ignore rest to be displayed.

output :

```
calling_no called_no call_date duration
9899767876 0112356788 01-jan-2012 163
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT c1.calling_no, 
       c1.called_no, 
       c1.call_date, duration =
       CASE
           WHEN c.duration > c1.duration THEN c.duration ELSE c1.duration
       END
  FROM cdr AS c INNER JOIN cdr1 AS c1 ON 
       c.calling_no = c1.calling_no AND 
       c.called_no = c1.called_no AND
       c.call_date = c1.call_date
 WHERE (SIGN(c.duration - c1.duration) * (c.duration - c1.duration)) > 1
```

**EDIT:** Updated the query taking into consideration that `cdr.duration` might be > `cdr1.duration`

Comment: @user2002843 i think the above `query` will give you the right answer, You can check the execution of both the queries [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0768f/6)

Comment: it is returning 0 rows selected

Answer (score 0):

This is code which will get you desired result:

```
SELECT  
    c.calling_no ,  
    c.called_no ,
    c.call_date ,
    c.duration
FROM Cdr c
    JOIN Cdr_01 c1
    ON c.calling_no = c1.calling_no 
       AND c.called_no = c1.called_no 
       AND c.calle_date = c1.call_date
WHERE  (c.duration - c1.duration) NOT IN (-1, 0, 1)
```